# State management of screens of Ionic 3 app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, state-management

I saw one of job post on `Upwork` where they have mentioned about `State management of screens`. First time I have heard about this. What was that? Can you tell me how can I implement such thing with `Ionic 3` app? Do I need to use any library to implement such pattern? Hope you'll share your experience about this pattern with me.

You can see about above requirement on [**This job post on Upwork**](https://www.upwork.com/jobs/~0194260cedab9ffb87).